# Replace environment variable place-holders with their actual value?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching, environment-variables

In my Application.properties file I am using a key and value like that

```
report.custom.templates.path=${CATALINA_HOME}\\\\Medic\\\\src\\\\main\\\\reports\\\\AllReports\\\\
```

I need to replace the `${CATALINA_HOME}` with its actual path:

`{CATALINA_HOME} = C:\Users\s57893\softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.27`

Here is my code:

```
public class ReadEnvironmentVar {  

 public static void main(String args[]) {

    String path = getConfigBundle().getString("report.custom.templates.path");
    System.out.println("Application Resources : " + path);
    String actualPath = resolveEnvVars(path);
    System.out.println("Actual Path : " + actualPath);

   }

private static ResourceBundle getConfigBundle() {
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle("medicweb");
 }

private static String resolveEnvVars(String input) {
    if (null == input) {
        return null;
     }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\w+)\\}|\\$(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String envVarName = null == m.group(1) ? m.group(2) : m.group(1);
        String envVarValue = System.getenv(envVarName);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, null == envVarValue ? "" : envVarValue);
     }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

from my code I am getting the result as -

Actual Path :

```
 C:Userss57893softwaresapache-tomcat-7.0.27\Medic\src\main\reports\AllReports\
```

but I need the result as -

Actual Path :

```
C:\Users\s57893\softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.27\Medic\src\main\reports\AllReports\
```

Please send me one example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way `appendReplacement()` works, you'll need to escape backslashes that you find in the environment variable. From [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, **and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.**

I would use:

```
m.appendReplacement(sb, 
    null == envVarValue ? "" : Matcher.quoteReplacement(envVarValue));
```